# What technologies would be useful to a society trying to attain elevation?

Tags: earth-like, technological-development

**Setting**

This question is about a human culture, with conditions essentially the same as Earth's with technology roughly comparable to early middle ages. The climate is roughly Alpine, although the mountain is taller than any on Earth.

**Society**

I've been playing around with a culture that values elevation (for essentially religious reasons). The people live on the slopes of a mountain and base their social standing on the height at which they live*. This leads them to live as high up the mountain as possible, even at a cost to their health or life expectancy.

The general social structure is therefore that the lower class (those living further down the mountain) farm the lower, more arable land while the upper class struggles to survive in smaller settlements on the less hospitable land higher up, relying at least partially on 'tithes' from those beneath them.

These people do have contact with civilisation beyond the mountain, so have ways to trade the mountain's goods (metals, gemstones) for exotic materials they can't obtain themselves.

**Question**

What technologies would this society develop in order to attain as much elevation as possible?

**Note**

Whether this society is feasible isn't part of the question. I'm aware that there are issues I haven't addressed that would cause this society to break down, but for the purpose of this question just assume everyone goes along with it.

---

*More accurately social standing is a function of average and maximum elevation. Someone who frequently makes trips up and down the mountain would be considered more important than someone with the same average elevation who doesn't travel. This means it is valuable to find ways to get higher even if it isn't permanent.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hello @JamieLear, welcome to [worldbuilding.se]. When you see that automated message from Community BOT, it's generally a bad sign. It means some aspect of your post failed to meet Stack Exchange's basic expectations for questions. In your case, you're asking more than one question, which is a literal reason to close the question (VTC:Needs More Focus). Further, you're asking us to brainstorm ideas, which we discourage. SE prefers specific, fairly objective questions. How will you judge a single best answer? From a worldbuilding perspective, what's your problem?

Comment: I ask because (a) you don't need an altimeter, look up to see who's above you and down to see who's below. (b) Elevators in the early middle ages were accomplished using block and tackle with ropes. (c) Your climbing expectation was answered by yourself, and (d) won't have a practical solution using early middle ages tech. Can you [edit] your question to focus on a single, solvable problem? Thanks

Comment: Thanks @JBH. I've edited the question to be narrower and cut out my ideas which since they weren't directly related to the new question. Hopefully the question is now sufficiently focussed to choose an answer.

Comment: It's better, but for future reference please note that SE prohibits open-ended questions (see [help/dont-ask]). For the most part, such questions on this stack are nothing more than idea-generation (brainstorming, see [help/on-topic]) questions. We recognize that, to a limited degree, some idea-generation is necessary for worldbuilding. But we have limits. Please read about the difference between on-topic [finite lists of things](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6138/40609) and off-topic [infinite lists of things](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6139/40609).

Comment: Elevators. Does that answer the question? Simple counterweighted lifts. Also, funiculars.

Comment: elevation was a status symbol in many real civilizations why not look at those?

Comment: @John that sounds promising, could you point me at something to read further into?

Comment: the maya were particularly famous for it, giant platforms to raise import things up everywhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me suggest that you aren't going to get an exact match for "middle ages" technology. You're describing a society of engineers who mine for a living, so I suspect they would develop a rail system comparatively early. When adjusting technology levels, I always identify something that's equivalently reduced. In this case, I suggest that they would have excellent stone carving but a lower level of woodworking and hydraulic systems.

The first railways don't show up in our history until 1600 or so. Previous to that, they used wooden wagons. Let's say your people considered their elevators to have the same importance as Roman highways or aqueducts. You'd have chains pulling iron-shod carts up stone railways, with counterweights. They would have something similar in their mines. If they advanced their metallurgy, they might even develop iron rails maybe a century before the outside world would.

Reliable elevators is actually the thing that prevented humans from making taller structures in most cultures. We could build twelve story masonry structures, but who wants to climb that many stairs? You have a similar issue distributing food and water to those places. If you have elevators, then you need something to power them. Water wheels will only get you so far.

At a higher level, you have to ask what activities are going on "higher up." Is this where people live and throw parties? Is it where they have business offices? Is this the seat of government, or just the monastic few? That will define the volume of traffic, and will specify the effort that they would go to for their transport system.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts. Counterweighted rails definitely seem like a good start, I was also imagining elevators working similarly. I agree that the limiting factor is ability to move food and other goods up the mountain. Regarding what people at the top are doing, they are basically trying to survive as high up as possible. The whole society is geared towards as many people being elevated as high as possible, so the volume of traffic ends up being as large as can be maintained.

Answer (score 1):

My thinking would be something along the lines of hot-air balloons. One of the core jobs of the peasants below could be building a maintaining of such devices in order to get goods quickly to the top of the mountain.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hello @christopherPearson, welcome to [worldbuilding.se]. That automated comment from Community BOT is a red flag that means your answer has failed to meet Stack Exchange's expectations. It's too short and fails to address (a) the value of this solution over others and (b) a list of its deficiencies such as what happens when hot air + the weight of the balloon and cargo can no longer rise higher on the mountain (at the very least). Stack Exchange doesn't prefer short answers and we don't prefer quick brainstorming comments. Could you please [edit] your answer to fully flesh it out?

Answer (score 1):

I would expect the elites to take the highest comfortable zone and just deny it and anything higher to everyone else as sacred ground or out of reach due to expense.

Similar strategies are in place everywhere already.

Comment: That doesn't really effect the technologies required either way. The elites are going to need ways to survive high in the mountain, and are still in competition with each other. Additionally elevation isn't valuable exclusively for comparison with others, even if someone lived higher than anyone else they'd still want to gain altitude (think of elevation gain as a religious mandate of the society).